# Will Mutex protection failed for register promotion?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, compiler-construction, mutex, memory-barriers

In an article about c++11 memory order, author show an example reasoning "threads lib will not work in c++03"

```
for (...){
  ...
  if (mt) pthread_mutex_lock(...);
  x=...x...
  if (mt) pthread_mutex_unlock(...);
}
//should not have data-race
//but if "clever" compiler use a technique called 
//"register promotion" , code become like this:

r = x;
for (...){
    ...
if (mt) {
    x=r; pthread_mutex_lock(...); r=x;
}
r=...r...
if (mt) {
    x=r; pthread_mutex_unlock(...); r=x;
}
x=r;
```

There are 3 question:

1.Is this promotion only break the mutex protection in c++03?What about c language?

2.c++03 thread libs become unwork?

3.Any other promotion may caused same problem?

If it's wrong example, then thread libs work, what about the 《Threads Cannot be Implemented as a Library》by Hans Boehm.

Comment: He meant that compilers designed for single threaded execution will not guarantee correct MT code generation in every case in presence of non trivial optimization (those that transform treat program fragments longer that single statements).

Answer (score 1):

POSIX functions `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` are memory barriers, the compiler and/or CPU cannot reorder loads and stores around them. Otherwise the mutexes would be useless. That article is probably inaccurate.

See [POSIX 4.12 Memory Synchronization](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11):

> Applications shall ensure that access to any memory location by more than one thread of control (threads or processes) is restricted such that no thread of control can read or modify a memory location while another thread of control may be modifying it. Such access is restricted using functions that synchronize thread execution and **also synchronize memory with respect to other threads**. The following functions synchronize memory with respect to other threads: [see the list on the website]

Comment: Thanks.But if it's wrong, then thread libs work, what about the 《Threads Cannot be Implemented as a Library》by Hans Boehm. I 'm sorry I'm not smart enough to read this difficult paper.

Comment: @P二零 That paper says that threads must be implemented by the OS, not a library. That is irrelevant here.

Comment: May I understand as "thread libs cannot be implemented as lib without support of OS"?

Comment: @P二零 Yes, you may.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin "_That paper says that threads must be implemented by the OS,_" Where does it say that?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin "green threads" can be implemented at the library level

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Which requirements you think wold be problematic? I don't think any safety requirement would be difficult. Forward progress is difficult when threads are paused waiting for I/O.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Emulation at the threading library level over either no kernel threads or less kernel threads. Advantage: allows the creation of much more user threads than you could create "real" threads. Limitation: all user threads mapped to one kernel will be paused until a syscall returns

Answer (score -1):

For single thread code, the state in the abstract machine is not directly observable: objects that aren't volatile are not guaranteed to have any particular state when you pause the only thread with a signal and observe it via `ptrace` or the equivalent. The only requirement is that the program execution has the same observable behavior as a behavior of one possible execution of the abstract machine.

The observables are the interactions with external world; basically, input/output on streams and actions on volatile objects.

A compiler for mono-thread code can generate code that perform operations on global variables or other object that happen to be shared between threads, as long as the single thread semantic is respected. This is obviously the case if a global variable to changed in such a way that it gets back its original value.

For example, a compiler might emit code that increment then decrement a variable, at least in some rare cases; the goal would be to emit simple code, at the cost of the occasional few unneeded operations.

Such changes to shared variables that don't exist in the abstract machine would obviously break multithreaded code that concurrently performs a real operation; such code does not have any race condition on the accesses of the shared variable, that are properly serialized, but the generated code introduced a race that breaks the program.

Comment: When do we have a  "designed for single thread compiler"? May include correct c/c++ compilers before c++11(memory model)?

Comment: By the way, may I consider your answer for my question as in c++03(compiler) thread libs cannot  always work correctly?

Comment: @P二零 Just because threads were not supported (or even mentioned) by either C/C++ std, doesn't imply compiler writers were ignorant of thread issues or unwilling to support threads. **Compiler documentation of thread support predates official std thread support by a decade.** F.ex. GCC was designed with the ability to use pthread in the mind of the compiler writers. In the real world compiler writers care about needs of programmers incl. threads. But just to claim std conformance, they don't have to.

Comment: A correct C/C++ middle end might make transformations that are unsafe in the presence of correct C/C++ threading code (code w/o a data race), by introducing a data race that doesn't exist in original code. This may be a legit optimization that mostly optimize through it's provably a potential pessimization in some cases, as there are additional writes to memory that isn't normally written to. But compilers are expected to do optimizations that are mostly better but sometimes are slightly inferior.